# How to redirect like this to the other website

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

Does anybody know how to redirect someone from a page like example.com/2458/233 to example2.com/2458/233?

On the first url, there is only a file who is redirecting to that other domain. Does anybody know how to do it?

A better explanation:

We have a URL example.com/222/222 and I only want an index file that would take the /222/222 and redirect to example2.com/222/222

Comment: Can you provide some more information? Like is this happening on the browser or do you want to redirect requests to example.com/2458/233 to example2.com/2458/233 on the server?

Comment: are you asking something like after login

Comment: @SerShubham I've just added a better explanation!

Comment: Is this meant to be an automated redirect, anyone who lands on this page goes to that page?

Comment: @elbrant Yes!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so just set the location with the pathname

```
window.location.href = 'http://www.example2.com' + window.location.pathname
```

This will not keep querystring or hash. If you want that, you can do a simple replacement/substring...

```
window.location.href = window.location.href.replace(window.location.origin, 'https://example2.com')
```

but in the end this is not good for SEO, better with a serverside redirect.

Comment: Is it going to work if on example.com/222/222 is no index & only on example.com?

Comment: Well you would need to set up the server to do something to load same page no matter what path.

Answer (score 0):

Name this "index.php".
Edit the location of the page you are redirecting to.
Save it to the directory that you want to send it from.

```
<?php
    /* no one should be here, send them away! */
        exit(header("Location: ../")); 
 ?>
```